# how to break loop from nested function?

Tags: php

Heres the problem

```
public function loop (){
    while($this->controlFunction()){
        //do stuff
    }
}
public function controlFunction (){
     $this->nestedFunction();
}

public function nestedFunction (){
   if($condA){ //whatsoever the condition
       break;
   } 
}
```

Is that possible ? I dont wanna return and then use a flag to return back again, seems like spaghetti code

Thanks for the answer guys, after thought, my question seems quite stupid though... Anyways thank you :)

Comment: Easy enough to test. Have you?

Comment: yes. the error is that  Cannot break/continue 1 level in

Comment: sounds like your 'main' function needs to be calling this function then

Answer (score 3):

As per [the documentation](https://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php):

```
break ends execution of the current for, foreach, while, do-while or switch structure
```

as calling a function changes the scope, the `break` statement will have no effect on the previous scope executing the `while`-loop.

In fact, because the scope is different than in the `nestedFunction` method, calling `break` will result in a fatal error (`E_ERROR`) because that scope is not aware of the `while`-loop running in the previous scope.

```
Fatal error: Cannot break/continue 1 level
```

So no, it is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried it yet? Regardless, returning a value is a better approach for clarity of what the function is supposed to do. You should always try to make functions independent, it is good practice.